# Как нарисовать круг в XML

Tags: android, xml

Как нарисовать незакрашенный круг (желательно с возможностью задавать ширину контура), который будет использоваться в android?

Картинка png страдает качеством, поэтому лучше использовать xml.

И еще он должен быть полностью прозрачным, кроме самой линии контура.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее как раз таки и надо использовать png. Просто надо грамотно картину разложить по папкам в drawable. Круг в xml нарисовать можно таким образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
 <size 
       android:width="65dp"
        android:height="65dp"/>
   <solid 
       android:color="@color/gray_dark"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: А как сделать его прозрачным?  Чтобы только контур остался. 
P.s - залить цветом как и фон - не получится, он может меняться.

Comment: укажите тогда  <solid android:color="@null"/> и добавьте <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/gray_dark" />

Comment: Получилось, большое спасибо!!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста

Comment: можно и не заливать, просто обрисовать фигуру.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно заливать фигуру (solid) просто, отрисуйте контур, пример:

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp"/>
<stroke android:color="#767676" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Если вы будете использовать, его как иконку, то советую поставить прозрачность цвета, как описано в guidline Google.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле можно использовать это, тут сразу кольцо и без танцев с параметрами и бубном

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
      android:thicknessRatio="5.333">
      <solid android:color="#7DBE15"/>
  </shape>
```